# Create a new order using rules and update the user profile of the order

Tags: commerce, rules

At a certain point when some conditions are met I need to create a new order using rules.
I manage to create the order, add the items but fail up get a user profile connected to the order.
When I try to use the Set a data value action to update the profile of the order (commerceorder:commerce-customer-billing:profile-id) the message is displayed "The selected data property doesn't support writing."
I have also tried to create a new user profile, set the values and then Set a Data Value action and pass on the new entity (commerceorder:commerce-customer-billing) but without success.

```
{ "rules_create_order_and_profile" : {
"LABEL" : "Create order and profile",
"PLUGIN" : "rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "commerce_cart", "commerce_checkout" ],
"IF" : [
  { "entity_has_field" : {
      "entity" : [ "site:current-cart-order" ],
      "field" : "commerce_customer_billing"
    }
  }
],
"DO" : [
  { "commerce_cart_product_add_by_sku" : {
      "USING" : { "user" : "4", "sku" : "10001", "quantity" : "1", "combine" : "1" },
      "PROVIDE" : { "product_add_line_item" : { "product_add_line_item" : "Added product line item" } }
    }
  },
  { "entity_create" : {
      "USING" : {
        "type" : "commerce_customer_profile",
        "param_type" : "billing",
        "param_user" : "4"
      },
      "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "entity_created" : "Created entity" } }
    }
  },
  { "data_set" : {
      "data" : [ "site:current-cart-order:commerce-customer-billing" ],
      "value" : [ "entity-created" ]
    }
  },
  { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "entity-created:uid" ], "value" : "4" } },
  { "data_set" : {
      "data" : [ "entity-created:commerce-customer-address:name-line" ],
      "value" : "Donald Duck"
    }
  },
  { "entity_save" : { "data" : [ "entity-created" ] } },
  { "commerce_checkout_complete" : { "commerce_order" : [ "site:current-cart-order" ] } }
]
```

}
}

Is this a problem related to saving the entities in the correct order, and what would be the correct sequence?